# How to use android as ble broadcaster?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

i want to create an app that send a little data with a ble broadcast. Is it possible to use BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_BROADCAST with BluetoothGattServer instance to do this task?
can it start advertising?

i'm searching some documentation but i not found any useful resourse.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of anyone advertising characteristic data on a characteristic that have the broadcast property set.

Most people use "service data" or "manufacturer specific data" instead if they have some specific data to advertise.

See https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/ble_advertising for examples.